# Update table in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena created from S3. I wanted to update the column values using the update table command. Is the UPDATE Table command not supported in Athena?

Is there any other way to update the table ?

Thanks

Comment: no, this isn't possible, you can create a new table or view with the update operation, or perform the data manipulation performed outside of athena and then load the data into athena.

Answer (score 4):

Athena only supports External Tables, which are tables created on top of some data on S3. Since the S3 objects are immutable, there is no concept of UPDATE in Athena. What you can do is create a new table using CTAS or a view with the operation performed there, or maybe use Python to read the data from S3, then manipulate it and overwrite it.